# How do I get the last mysqli query executed before an exception occurs in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, exception, mysqli, try-catch

Here is some sample code:

```
try
{
   $db->query($sql_q1);
   $db->query($sql_q2);
   $db->query($sql_q3);
}
catch (Exception $e) 
{
   echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

How can I see which query caused the error in `catch` so I can see it along with the error message? And a line number won't work do me, because my queries are often dynamically built.

Comment: You tagged as mysqli, so have you gone over the manual yet? What isn't working the way you'd like it to? You didn't say.

Comment: Right now it's only showing the error message, not the actual SQL that is causing the error itself. Sometimes the error messages don't contain enough information for me to solve the problem.

Comment: What about `$db->error`? Is there not enough information in there?

Comment: Nope, that's the same message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all, just like Usman Munir said, if you won't catch it, there will be more information than if you catch. Just try to remove that `try..catch` stuff from your code and you will see the first 15 characters of the query.

But in case you need the entire query, there is a way, though not that it will give it to you right away, like a designated variable that contains specifically "last executed query", but well technically you *can*

There is a thing called a *stack trace*, intended for the exact purpose. It can show you all the calls made in your code that led to the error, including all function parameters.

Change your code to this

```
try
{
   $db->query($sql_q1);
   $db->query($sql_q2);
   $db->query($sql_q3);
}
catch (Exception $e) 
{
   var_dump($e->getTrace());
   // or to get the full error info, just
   var_dump($e);
}
```

and you will see your query in the full glory, though it will be quite a pain to get the actual query automatically if that's your goal. but if you want to just log/visually inspect the error information, it will do.

Not that obviously you should never put var_dump() inside try_catch() in any real life code. Instead, some handling code must be put into your *error handler*. Especially if your purpose is debugging. Hence, your real life code should be rather this

```
// somewhere in the bootstrap
include 'error_handler.php';

// anywhere in your code
$db->query($sql_q1);
$db->query($sql_q2);
$db->query($sql_q3);
```

and in the error_handler.php you can add a code to print the full stack trace. an example for such a file you can find in the article Usman Munir posted a link to (which incidentally I wrote).

Note that stack traces tend to grow *really* big, and can litter your logs significantly. So consider making extended output optional.

Comment: Thank you, I'll follow your advice. For right now for debugging I am just using `$last_query = json_encode($e->getTrace());` to store the logs a MySQL database in a JSON table type when an error occurs. I'll continue to improve my error handling going forward.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution if you are trying to know the previously executed query would be to store your SQL in a single variable and change it for each statement. Then if an error occurs with a query you can just echo out the contents of the variable. Unless there is a specific reason you need to have multiple variables to hold your queries.

Comment: I thought about that, but there is a reason I need different ones, sorry.